# Automate PostgreSQL scripts from azure devops without installing any client tools/drivers on my local machine

Tags: postgresql, github, azure-devops

My requirement is - Automate the PostgreSQL scripts from azure devops without installing any client tools/drivers on my local machine. We have couple of .sql, .fct and .prc files in repository. Pipeline should pickup these files and connect azure Postgres server and run the scripts.

Comment: PostgreSQL is integrated in the Microsoft hosted agent, you can consider using the hosted agent to run the pipeline.  About the software installed on the hosted agent,please refer to this [document](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#databases).

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is integrated in the Microsoft hosted agent, you can consider using the hosted agent to run the pipeline.

[image]

About the software installed on the hosted agent,please refer to this [document](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#databases).

Comment: Hi Hugh Lin, Thanks for response , I didn't find any PostgreSQL  related task to add an agent job.